# react not updating child components visually after setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

After deleting an "infraction" on the child component I update the state in the parent component, however the changes are not being updated visually.  In the state it updates, however does not refresh the child component.  It may be something to do with shallow updates but I am unsure how to fix it.

Also my updatedData updates but the state does not update straight away.

Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code

```
delClick = (id) => {
    console.log('id when it come in: ', id);
    const updatedData = this.state.students.map((student) => {
        return {
            ...student,
            infractions: student.infractions.filter((infraction) => {
                return infraction.id !== id;
            }),
        };
    });
    console.log('updataed data: ', updatedData);
    this.setState({
        students: updatedData,
    });
    console.log('state students: ', this.state.students);
};
```

Comment: can you share how your state looks?

Answer (score 0):

When your nextState depends on the old one, You should pass a function to update your state like this:

```
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            return {
               students:  prevstate.students.map((student) => {
                   return {
                    ...student,
                    infractions: student.infractions.filter((infraction) => infraction.id !== id;),
                   };
              });
            };
   });
```

Comment: Tried it this way with the same result, it is not updating the child components but the state is still getting updated

Answer (score 0):

setState is an asynchronous function.
Try this:

```
 this.setState({
     students: updatedData, 
 },() => {
     console.log(this.state.students);
 });
```

Comment: Yes sure it is asynchronous, but it is still not updating the child component